# Converting 4 uint_8 values to float in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a system that sends frames of sensor data via bluetooth to a host computer. The host runs a python program that processes the sensor data. The sensor data consists for float(32) values from c code on a development kit board. These values are split into 4 bytes(uint_8). I want to convert the these values back to float32. I've tried various solutions but none seems to work. Any ideas?

I've tried using the struct.pack/struct.unpack functions, but I am either misunderstanding the usage or there is something else that is wrong. 
Intput example: 
[22, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 230, 254, 255, 255....

```
def int2bytes(i):
    hex_value = '{0:x}'.format(i)
    # make length of hex_value a multiple of two
    hex_value = '0' * (len(hex_value) % 2) + hex_value
    return codecs.decode(hex_value, 'hex_codec')

def convert_from_byte(data):
    byte_array = [0]*4
    byte_count = 0
    float_count = 0
    data_size = len(data)
    data_float = [] * 247
    for i in range(data_size):
        byte_array[byte_count] = int2bytes(data[i])
        if(byte_count==3):
            byte_array = ''.join(byte_array)
            data_float[float_count] =struct.unpack('<f', byte_array)
            float_count += 1
            byte_count = 0
        byte_count += 1
    return data_float
```

I expect the values to be around 0.005 but it can vary by a lot.

Comment: Just to be clear, [22,132,0,0] is the first float, [0,0,199,230] is the second, etc. etc?

Comment: how about `struct.unpack('<f', bytes([22, 132, 0, 0]))` ? It doesn't need `int2bytes` and you can use `data[:4]` - `struct.unpack('<f', bytes(data[:4]))` - and then get `data = data[4:]`

Answer (score 2):

I believe your inputs are incorrect. Intuitively,  [22,132,0,0] and [0,0,199,230] are vastly different numbers, with zeros in the high order bytes in the first and low order in the second.

You can convert quite easily from 4 unsigned bytes to floats with the following. In this example I'll use 4 bytes in big-endian format to match the first example (see [single-precision examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)) in Wikipedia. So just the low-order bit set as in `[0, 0, 0, 1]`

```
import struct
>>>struct.unpack('>f', struct.pack('4B', *[0,0,0,1]))
(1.401298464324817e-45,)
```

So pack 4 bytes, then unpack as big-endian floats. You can do little endian floats the same way, just by reversing the input and the float endian specifier.

```
>>> struct.unpack('<f', struct.pack('4B', *[1,0,0,0]))
(1.401298464324817e-45,)
```

When I try your data it's nothing like what you are expecting, so I suspect the inputs your are getting are wrong.

```
data = [22, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 230,]
>>> struct.unpack('<f',struct.pack('4B', *data[:4]))
(4.738350627267936e-41,)
>>> struct.unpack('<f',struct.pack('4B', *data[4:8]))
(-4.698754650455297e+23,)
```

So one result is 38 orders of magnitude too small, and the other is 26 too high. In any case, you can use the above methods to convert bytes to float once you figure out why the inputs are messed up.

Finally the same process for all bytes in the list to create a list of floats.

```
[struct.unpack('<f',struct.pack('4B', *data[i:i+4]))[0] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my inquiry.

Comment: I was wrong with my prediction. I was thinking of processed sensor data. 
[  6.07065530e-03   2.17261743e-02  -2.90762056e-02 ...,  -1.52583336e-04
   7.74722648e-05   2.58271320e-05]
This is more like what i was expecting. Still pretty far off though.

Comment: So if the values in the list are wrong I can see two possibilities. One, which seems unlikely these days, is that the floating point format of whatever is giving you the data is different from the one most commonly used. More likely, there is something unknown going on in the delivery of data to your application. I would expect the latter, especially as the first and second examples are so vastly different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data[:4]` to get four numbers, `bytes()` to convert to bytes, and then you can use it with struct. After that you can cut off these four numbers - `data = data[4:]`

```
import struct

def convert_from_byte(data):

    results = []

    while data:
        part = data[:4]
        value = struct.unpack('<f', bytes(part))
        results.append(value[0])
        data = data[4:]

    return results

data = [22, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 230, 254, 255, 255, 0]
convert_from_byte(data)

# [4.738350627267936e-41, -4.698754650455297e+23, 2.3509884213848822e-38]
```

You can also use `range(len())` and `data[i:i+4]` to use probably less memory

```
def convert_from_byte(data):

    results = []

    for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
        part = data[i:i+4]
        value = struct.unpack('<f', bytes(part))
        results.append(value[0])

    return results

data = [22, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 230, 254, 255, 255, 0]
convert_from_byte(data)

# [4.738350627267936e-41, -4.698754650455297e+23, 2.3509884213848822e-38]
```

This can be even write as list comprehensions

```
def convert_from_byte(data):
    return [struct.unpack('<f', bytes(data[i:i+4]))[0] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]

data = [22, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 230, 254, 255, 255, 0]
convert_from_byte(data)

# [4.738350627267936e-41, -4.698754650455297e+23, 2.3509884213848822e-38]
```

Comment: Yes, `bytes` on the input side is cleaner than `struct`. It gets the same answer though which is way different to what he was expecting.

Comment: @Deepstop values are much different then expected 0.005 even if we use `'>f'` instead of `'<f'` but maybe expections are wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not push the 8 bits into the 32 bit float with bitwise operators

```
data_float += (byte_array[0] << 24)
data_float += (byte_array[1] << 16)
data_float += (byte_array[2] << 8)
data_float += (byte_array[3])
float_array[i] = data_float
```

Comment: This won't work. You are just adding integer values of the shifted numbers, which will yield the wrong result.

Comment: Isn't that what he was asking for? The sensor has some 32 bit float that it converts into 4 8 bit values to send over the air, and need to be added back together to get the original 32 bit number again. I'm not really trying to fix the original code, this is the same functions I use for my arduino 2.4ghz RF sensors

Comment: The concept would work in C if the float were part of a union with the byte array. In your answer `data_float` will be an integer, just like the elements in `byte_array`, but the result needs to be a floating point number. There may be a library (there usually is) that can create a `union` between the integer representation and the internal floating point representation, like you can in C, but   it won't happen automatically.

Comment: Correct about the C. I glossed over the Python syntax/style a bit but the bitwise functions in Python seem to be the same/similar to in C. One of the sensors I use returns floats from a temperature reader with 2 decimal place, this gets converted into a 32 bit integer, chopped into a uint8 array and transmitted using a radio stack, I reassemble it with the bitwise functions but in a pattern like this. After there is a function call that really simply returns the int back to 2 digit decimal place (ex: 5515 becomes 55.15) I guess the key here is knowing exactly the decimal place

Comment: In this case the bytes are a floating point representation. The 32 bit standard for floating point is 1 sign bit, 8 bits of exponent, and 23 bit significand (aka mantissa) with an implied leading 1 bit. So it is not a conversion from floating point but the floating point value as it is stored by the machine architecture. So it is not sufficient just to reassemble the bits but also to convince Python to treat those bits as a floating point value. In your example, you converted to a 32 bit integer before chopping it into `uint8`

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot I was ignorant of this standard. I was mostly intrigued by the sensor part :) Maybe the Asker could try to convert his floats to before transmitting them and then it would be easier to reassemble it. Again thank you very much for this bit of knowledge